# How can we make it in Lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

first we must declare interface in other file or same file for lambda expression.But if can we do that in method declaration that will be more easier.is there anyway?

```
 public class LambdaAppJava8 {
 public int fonk(
     int a, 
     int b, 
     interface MyInterface{
          public int call(int a, int b);
     } anonim
 ) {
    return anonim.call(a, b);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    LambdaAppJava8 app = new LambdaAppJava8();
    System.out.println(app.fonk(1, 3, (c, d) -> c + d));
 }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? I added java-8 tag for this.

Comment: you added i accepted.what is the wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to declare an interface right inside the method declaration but you can make it a nested type which is close enough.

```
public class LambdaAppJava8 {
    private interface MyInterface {
        public int call(int a, int b);
    }
    public int fonk(int a, int b, MyInterface anonim) {
        return anonim.call(a, b);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LambdaAppJava8 app = new LambdaAppJava8();
        System.out.println(app.fonk(1, 3, (c, d) -> c + d));
    }
}
```

It also seems that there in a misunderstanding in the implication of an anonymous `interface`. You can declare anonymous classes inside a method but these are not declared “on-the-fly”; they are still types created at compile-time having their own class file which isn’t smaller than a top-level type, actually, it’s the opposite. Such types have *bigger* class files than top-level types as they contain meta-information about the surrounding context in which they are defined.

That wouldn’t change if there was a way to declare an `interface` inside the parameter list of a method; it wouldn’t be more efficient than declaring it anywhere else. But it would require special scoping rule exceptions as under normal scoping rules you couldn’t call a method which expects a parameter of a type local to the method as the caller wouldn’t know that type.

---

But note that the example above is what you want to achieve, practically. You can also change the declaration of `MyInterface` to `public` and other classes could invoke the method with a lambda expression like with the use case `app.fonk(1, 3, (c, d) -> c + d)` *without the need to import* `MyInterface`. Which is what your question seems to be about, callers don’t have to deal with the `interface` specifically defined for the `fonk` parameter, the compiler does.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way of doing this in java, you cannot declare an anonymous class/interface in a method deceleration.

If you are looking for a solution for that specific scenario then I would suggest:

```
public int fonk(
     int a, 
     int b, 
     BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> anonim
 ) {
    return anonim.apply(a, b);
 }
```

According to: [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html)

Comment: thanks for answer.this solution is spesific.not common.i can't declare other type variables,more than 3 etc.

Comment: Then you'll need to declare another top-level interface with the variables you want.

Comment: Also [`IntBinaryOperator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;


public class LambdaAppJava8 {
    public static int fonk(int a, int b,int c,
             BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Integer> func
         ) {
            return func.apply(func.apply(a, b),c);
         }
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        int sum = fonk(1,2,3,(x,y)->x+y);
        int product = fonk(1,2,3,(x,y)->x*y);
        System.out.println(sum);
        System.out.println(product);
    }
}
```